# How can I kill Spark application using a rest call?

Tags: rest, apache-spark

I run Spark in both client and cluster mode. Is there any rest url that can be used to kill running spark apps and drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment Spark has a [hidden REST API](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api). It's likely that in the future it will be public (see issue [SPARK-12528](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12528)). However, at the moment it's still "private", so you should use it at your own risk - meaning that if something changes in the API of the next Spark version, you need to update your code.

Otherwise, you can use [Spark-server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver), but this will bring along more packages/dependencies, which you might not need.

Answer (score 2):

curl -X PUT   'http://localhost:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1524528223375_0082/state' -d '{"state": "KILLED"}'

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_State_API

Answer (score 0):

If running on yarn, you can use "yarn application -kill application_XXXX_ID" to kill a application.

This command can also be issued using YARN REST APIs, with an decent description of calls listed [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/ch_yarn_rest_apis.html) or in the [official docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html)

The blog post [apache-spark-hidden-rest-api](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api) uses actually the YARN REST API.

Thus said, the above is possible only on YARN.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that you need YARN: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5388 It explicitly mentions Spark Standalone - therefore, no Yarn needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you have submissionId:-

```
curl -X POST http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/kill/driver-20151008145126-0000
```